# How to make different rules in yii2, depends on the radiobutton value?

Tags: php, yii2

I'm a begginer so sorry if it's obvious. So, I would like different rules depends on what the user select. I have an update form:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'news_title')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'news_content')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'check')->label('Picture update:')
        ->radioList(
                [ 2 => 'Yes', 1 => 'No', 0 => 'Delete']) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'file')->fileInput() ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

And only if the radioList has a value '2' I would like to require the fileInput. I mean if the user select 1 => 'No', or 0 => 'Delete' the fielInput can be empty.

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['news_content'], 'string'],
        [['news_content'], 'required'],
        [['created_at', 'updated_at'], 'safe'],
        [['news_title', 'news_picture', 'created_by', 'updated_by'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['news_title'], 'required'],
        [['news_picture'], 'required'],
        [['file'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => $this->checkRadio(), 'extensions' => 'png, jpg',],
        [['check'], 'required', 'message' => 'Please ....'],
    ];
}
public function checkRadio() {
    if ($this->check == 2) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I tried to write a function in the model but the $check variable always has a 0 value and I don't really understand why. Is there any solution in Yii2 for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#conditional-validation) which is quite straight forward but something like this should be sufficient

```
[
    'file', 'required',
    'when' => function ($model) {
        return $model->check == 2;
    },
    'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
                return $('#signupform-check-2').is(':checked');
    }",
    'message' => 'Please....'
]
```

As long as you have client validation enabled, you always have to do two checks. backend and front end.

Comment: In this case the file always required for me.

Comment: I edited my answer and tested it out on the real form. The point here is that you target the correct radio button in your whenClient validation.

Answer (score -1):

```
***********  Your Controller Like This ***********************

 public function actionCreate(){
    $model = new Model();
    if(Yii::$app->request->post())
    {
     if($model->check ==2)
       {
        $model->scenario ='fileInputRequired';
       }
        else{
           $model->scenario ='fileInputNotRequired';
            }
    }
   if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
 }


********** Your Model Like This *****************

public function rules() {
    return [

        [['news_content','news_title','news_picture','check'], 'required'],
        [['news_content'], 'string'],
        [['created_at', 'updated_at'], 'safe'],
        [['news_title', 'news_picture', 'created_by', 'updated_by'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['file'], 'file', 'on' =>'fileInputRequired', 'extensions' => 'png, jpg',],
       ];
}
 function scenario()
{
    return [
        'fileInputRequired' => ['news_content', 'news_picture', 'news_title','file','check'];
        'fileInputNotRequired' => ['news_content', 'news_picture','news_title','check'];
}
```

Comment: I try it in a simple example.. If i put the scenario after the post() it doesn't work. :\

Comment: Never, ever, do something like this for simple validations.